a doubt about hint of stein Complex Analysis chapter2,exercise 7

Exercise:Suppose $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic.   Show that the diameter$d=sup_{z,\omega\in\mathbb{D}}|f(z)-f(\omega)|$ of the image of $f$ satisfies
$$2|f^{'}(0)|\leq d$$

Hint:  $2f^{'}(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\varsigma|=r}^{} \frac{f(\varsigma)-f(-\varsigma)}{\varsigma^{2}}d\varsigma$ whenever $0<r<1$
My doubt is that whether the equation in the hints still holds if $r\geq 1$.    if it still holds,Since
$$
|2f^{'}(0)|\leq \frac{d}{2\pi}\int_{|\varsigma|=r}^{} \frac{1}{|\varsigma^{2}|}d\varsigma=\frac{d}{r} 
$$$f^{'}(0)$ must be $0$,but I haven't found the reason which can show the equation doesn't hold when $r\geq 1$.

Simply because f is assumed to be holomorphic on the unit disk only. There may by singularities on the boundary $r=1$

You have already proved that $|2f'(0)| \le \frac  d r$ for every $r<1$. Just take limit as $ r $ tends to $1$.
Note that $f(\zeta)$ in the integral is not defined if $r 
\ge 1$.

Thanks,I know how to address the exercise,I want to know whether the equation in hint still holds when $r\geq 1$.

Since $f$ is defined only on $\mathbb D$, the equation does not even make sense for $r\ge 1$. @kkk
